# How do I make a batch file that can run certain commands based on the date?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I was wondering how to make a batch file that runs a certain command/commands based on the date. I have a script that is based on the day of the week:

```
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Mon CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Tue CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Wed CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Thu CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Fri CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Sat CALL (File/program/directory)

IF %DATE:~0,3%==Sun CALL (File/program/directory)
```

But I need one more specific, like it runs a program on someone's birthday.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use the task scheduler/AT to run the file?

Comment: I am not just trying to get the job done, I'm expanding my knowledge of batch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it the same way like your current solution, it should be simple.
But it depends on your date/time format.

```
if "%DATE:~9,5%"=="11/04" call birthdayOfPeter.bat
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is very useful information. Do you know where I can get a list of date formats?

Answer (score 0):

There is another method to do it.

this code will start your program on `11/02/2014` (edit when ever you want to start)
copy `anything.bat` to startup

type this in `anything.bat`:

```
@echo off          
:finddate      
if %date% GEQ 11/02/2014 goto start  
goto finddate

:start  
start "your program"   
goto end   
:end
```